# Superconducting density of states

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

Consider a nonconventional superconducting order paramer $\Delta(k)$ either of singlet pairing $\Delta(k) =\psi(k) i\sigma_2$ or triplet pairing $\Delta(k) = (d(k)\cdot \sigma)i\sigma_2$ where $d$ is a vector and $\sigma$ is the vector of Pauli matrices.

I have read papers (e.g., [1]) claiming that if the Fermi Surface has point nodes, e.g., $\Delta(k) = \Delta_0 (\hat{k}_1 +i\hat{k}_2)\sigma_0$, then the density of states $\rho(E)$ of the BCS Hamiltonian is quadratic, i.e., $\rho \propto E^2$ for $E\sim 0$, and if we have line nodes, e.g., $\Delta(k) = \Delta_0 \hat{k}_3 \sigma_0$, then $\rho(E)\propto E$ is linear for small $E$.

However, I can't seem to find a proof. Any help would be appreciated.

[1] M. Sigrist and K. Ueda. "Phenomenological theory of unconventional superconductivity". Rev. Mod. Phys. 63, 239 (1991)

**EDIT**. So I think I understand the general idea of the proof. For example, consider a point node $p$ in the fermi surface. For sufficiently small $\omega$, the level set such that $E_k=\omega$ can only be a small surface near the point node $p$, and thus you would imagine that the surface area (in 3D) of such a small surface would be asymptotically proportional to $\omega^2$, i.e., $S =c \omega^2 +o(\omega^2)$. Notice that the definition of the density of states is given by
$$
\rho(\omega)=\int_{E_k=\omega} \frac{d\Omega_k}{|\nabla E_k|}
$$
where $d\Omega_k$ is the surface volume of the level set $E_k =\omega$. If we assume that $p$ is not a van-Hove singularity of $E_k$, i.e., $\nabla E_p \ne 0$, we could probably approximate (for sufficiently small $\omega$)
$$
\rho(\omega) \approx \frac{1}{|\nabla E_p|} S(E_k=\omega) 
$$
where $S(E_k=\omega)$ is the surface area of the level set $E_k=\omega$ and thus $\rho(\omega) \propto \omega^2$ for sufficiently small $\omega$. You can do something similar for line nodes.

*With that said*, there's still some places that is a little hard to justify rigorously (mainly the fact that $S$ is asymptotically $\propto \omega^2$), so I would still appreciate a rigorous proof under relatively general assumptions.